Ionic iOS capacitor Project Local notification method not get called both "will present" and "DidRecieve"
In iOS capacitor project I have implemented local notification from native iOS side, import UserNotifications and also write below mentioned code On did finish launching for configure. When I write this code on demo project then will present and didrecieve notification delegate method called successfully. but when I try to implement from iOS capacitor projects then will present and did receive method not called,is there any other configurations for ionic iOS capacitor?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            print("Notification authorization granted")
        } else {
            print("Notification authorization denied")
        }
    }
   
    
    return true
}

extension AppDelegate
{
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Handle notification
    
    completionHandler()
}}

 func scheduleNotification(title: String, body: String, timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Notification scheduled successfully")
            }
        }
    }

I have tried above mentioned code.its completely worked on native iOS project but in ionic iOS capacitor project not worked.
